# using location== for specifying multiple URLs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm hiding content based on specific URLs.

I have done this declaring one specific URL and it worked fine, but I am trying to declare multiple; the below attempt didn't work, even with a comma seperating.

```
  if(location=="http://domainone.com/" "http://domaintwo.com/index.php/my-catalog/single-item-view") {
```

Comment: As a side note to my answer, your javascript should act on the content present on the page instead of the url, your current approach will become quite messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(location=="http://domainone.com/" || location == "http://domaintwo.com/index.php/my-catalog/single-item-view") {
```

The `||` symbol means "or", which means that the entire condition will result in `true` if any of the conditions are true. This is compared to `&&` which means "and," meaning that the entire condition will be true only if all of the conditions are true.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a [logical operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) to combine multiple conditions:

```
if (
    location == "http://domainone.com/" ||
    location == "http://domaintwo.com/index.php/my-catalog/single-item-view"
)
```

Or you could use an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of acceptable URLs and check if the current `location` is inside your `whitelist` array.

```
var whitelist = [
    "http://domainone.com/",
    "http://domaintwo.com/index.php/my-catalog/single-item-view"
];
if (whitelist.indexOf(window.location) != -1)
```